# JPA ddl-auto=create/update with schema= mentioned in Entity not working with spring boot 2.1

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring boot application, with following User entity class:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {
...
```

and I'm using ddl-auto=update (or create) to auto-generate the schema in the database. The database used is H2 (also tried with HSQL).

Now all works well (the required table is automatically generated when application is launched), until the entity class is changed to the following (added schema=):

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="user", schema="myschm")
public class User {
...
```

Now it gives the error when creating the table: Schema "MYSCHM" not found. It seems JPA is expecting the schema MYSCHM to be present and not creating it automatically.

I started observing this issue after using Spring Boot 2.1.5. This used to work when I was using Spring Boot 1.5.3.
Is there any change made in Spring Boot 2+ that affects this? Is there any configuration change I need to do to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using in-memory db?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema is not auto created by H2.

You have to add:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS MYSCHM
```